# sessionScope.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME doesn't print anything after login

Tags: spring, jsf-2, spring-security

i followed the configuration in the following sample:

http://facestutorials.icefaces.org/tutorial/spring-security-basic.html

and i am trying to print the logged in username after successful login
but it doesn't print anything, any ideas why ?

code:

```
#{sessionScope.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME}
```

please advise.